# Plotly: How to display individual value on histogram?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to make dynamic plots with plotly. I want to plot a count of data that have been aggregated (using groupby).
I want to facet the plot by color (and maybe even by column). The problem is that I want the value count to be displayed on each bar. With histogram, I get smooth bars but I can't find how to display the count:
[image]

With a bar plot I can display the count but I don't get smooth bar and the count does not appear for the whole bar but for each case composing that bar
[image]

Here is my code for the barplot

```
val = pd.DataFrame(data2.groupby(["program", "gender"])["experience"].value_counts())
px.bar(x=val.index.get_level_values(0), y=val, color=val.index.get_level_values(1), barmode="group", text=val)
```

It's basically the same for the histogram.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you post the value of `data2`, please? Or you can post the actual file if you're using any

Comment: @Joris Thank you for accepting my suggestion. How did it work out for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[px.histogram](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/) does not seem to have a text attribute. So if you're willing to do any binning before producing your plot, I would use [px.Bar](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/). Normally, you apply text to your barplot using `px.Bar(... text = <something>)`. But this gives the results you've described with text for all subcategories of your data. But since we know that `px.Bar` adds data and annotations in the order that the source is organized, we can simply update text to the *last* subcategory applied using `fig.data[-1].text = sums`. The only challenge that remains is some data munging to retrieve the correct sums.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code with data example:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                       'y1':[1, 4, 9, 16],
                       'y2':[1, 4, 9, 16],
                       'y3':[6, 8, 4.5, 8]})
df = df.set_index('x')

# calculations
# column sums for transposed dataframe
sums= []
for col in df.T:
    sums.append(df.T[col].sum())

# change dataframe format from wide to long for input to plotly express
df = df.reset_index()
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['x'], value_vars = df.columns[1:])

fig = px.bar(df, x='x', y='value', color='variable')
fig.data[-1].text = sums

fig.update_traces(textposition='inside')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your first graph is with graph object librairy you can try:

```
# Use textposition='auto' for direct text
fig=go.Figure(data[go.Bar(x=val.index.get_level_values(0),
 y=val, color=val.index.get_level_values(1), 
 barmode="group", text=val, textposition='auto',
    )])
```